# Datetime Picker Validation

Tags: jquery, datetime

```
$.validator.addMethod("enddate", function (value, element) {
  var startdatevalue = $('#StartDate').val();
  return Date.parse(startdatevalue) < Date.parse(value);
});
```

How to reduce one day of start date ... i need to check start date greater than or equal to End Date using jquery

Comment: Hi yogee, that's not related to this question, but you should really mark some of your questions answered, or people won't be really eager to answer your questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`date.js`](http://www.datejs.com/) is my go to library when it comes to anything date/time related. The documentation is here:

> http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

You could try something like this:

```
end.add(1).days();
```

using date.js. Or just use the handy compare functions:

```
if ( start.isBefore(end) || start.equals(end) ) { ... }
```

One trick I have used in the past with the jQuery datepicker is to use two controls - a start datepicker, and an end datepicker.  Any time the start datepicker changes you can reset the minimum date of the end picker to be equal to or greater than the start datepicker's current value.

```
$('#secondRoundStartDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', start);
```